# JavaFX - Retrieving the WebView instance that issued a URLConnection

Tags: java, ajax, webview, javafx-8, urlconnection

Like in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21353856/javafx-webengine-wait-for-ajax-to-complete), I'd like to **wait for an AJAX request to be processed completely**. As you can see in [my reply there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33260848/3856838), I have managed to do so with the help of subclassing `HttpURLConnection`, redirecting the original input stream to one that I have control over and thus being able to say when the entire response has been retrieved from the server. However, with my programme opening several `WebView` instances in different windows, **I don't know which of these browsers actually created my url connection** and thus has now finished loading. Any help on how to determine that is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: *"Look at my post there for important details about your question"* is not an excuse not to include those details in this post (especially if there is no link to your answer). Those details have to be included in the question, otherwise it's off topic (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic *in the question itself*)

Comment: Done. Only meant to keep my question short and still provide background for those who'd like to have it.